# Async not working on jest for Vue2 UnitTesting

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-router

Hi I'm trying to cover a UI project with unit tests using Jest. Starting with the small bits and pieces so I can get on the flow of work. There's a file called SilentSignIn:

```
<template >
  <div class="app flex-row align-items-center">
    <div class="container vld-parent">
      <b-row class="justify-content-center">
        <b-col md="8" lg="5" sm="10" xs="12">
          <b-card-group>
            <b-card no-body class="p-4">
              <b-card-body >
                <div class="body-logo-container">
                  <img src="/img/test.png" class="pb-4" alt="Test" />
                </div>
                <b-row >
                  <b-col cols="12">
                    <h3 class="text-center pb-3">
                      Signing you in to TEST
                    </h3>
                  </b-col>
                </b-row>
              </b-card-body>
            </b-card>
          </b-card-group>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { vuexOidcProcessSilentSignInCallback } from "vuex-oidc";

export default {
  name: "SilentSignInCallback.vue",
  mounted() {
    vuexOidcProcessSilentSignInCallback();

    this.$router.push({ name: "dashboard" });
  }
};
</script>
```

On Jest I want to make sure that the Image is showing so I wrote the following:

```
import { screen, render } from "@testing-library/vue";
import SilentSignInCallback from '@/views/SilentSignInCallback';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import { BRow, BCol, BCardGroup, BCard, BCardBody } from "bootstrap-vue";
import { createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';

function setup(){
    const localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(VueRouter)
    const router = new VueRouter({
        routes: [
            {
                path: "/dashboard",
                name: "dashboard",
            }
        ]});

    render(SilentSignInCallback,{ 
        localVue,
        router,
        stubs: {
            'b-row': BRow,
            'b-col': BCol,
            'b-card-group': BCardGroup,
            'b-card': BCard,
            'b-card-body': BCardBody
        }
    });
}

describe('page rendering tests.', () => {
    it('has log-in image.', () => {
        setup();

        const tfImage = screen.getByAltText('TripFocus');

        console.log(tfImage);
    });
})
```

That gives me success:

[image]

But as soon as I try to use findByAltText (which uses await) code for jest changes like this:

```
import { screen, render } from "@testing-library/vue";
import SilentSignInCallback from '@/views/SilentSignInCallback';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import { BRow, BCol, BCardGroup, BCard, BCardBody } from "bootstrap-vue";
import { createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';

function setup(){
    const localVue = createLocalVue();
    localVue.use(VueRouter)
    const router = new VueRouter({
        routes: [
            {
                path: "/dashboard",
                name: "dashboard",
            }
        ]});

    render(SilentSignInCallback,{ 
        localVue,
        router,
        stubs: {
            'b-row': BRow,
            'b-col': BCol,
            'b-card-group': BCardGroup,
            'b-card': BCard,
            'b-card-body': BCardBody
        }
    });
}

describe('page rendering tests.', () => {
    it('has log-in image.', async () => {
        setup();
        const tfImage = await screen.findByAltText('TripFocus');
        console.log(tfImage);
    });
})
```

It fails:

[image]

I would like to know why is this happening. I can leave as is but it messes with my mind why async makes too much difference and what do I have to do so it accepts it.

I rolled back to having it without async since that works, other than that I seemed to come to a dead end if someone could help I could be forever grateful!